# yad - working with variable

Tags: linux, shell, user-interface, variables

I want create one GUI window and from this interface choose path to files and set up parameters and then run whole shell script.

my solution is:

```
files=$(zenity --file-selection --multiple --separator='' --title "Choose my files")
```

export files

```
parameters=$(yad --width 500 --height 500 --title "Whole parameters" --form --field="Threshold1" --field="Threshold2" --field="Threshold3")
```

Then I can use those parameters in my other shell commands..

It is possible to create one GUI window and there choose path to files, parameters an so on... And use those variables in my shell script?

Something like:

```
parameters=$(yad --width 500 --height 500 --title "Whole parameters" --file-selection --form --field="Threshold1" --field="Threshold2" --field="Threshold3")
```

Thank you for any help and advice..

Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer.. It could looks like this:

```
files=$(yad --width 800 --height 600 --title "GUI PROGRAM" \
    --form \
    --field="Laboratory:":RO "Laboratory" \
    --field="Memory:":NUM "VALUE[!2..64[!2]]" \
    --field="Click to select files":MFL "" \
    --field="Please Select Your Working Directory":DIR "C" \
```